# How does the method assigns the array?

Tags: java

*I am confused about how the array was assigned to any data, as the method meant to be a self contain
or I haven't understood a fundamental concept*

```
// Craft stall stock and till program   
import java.util.Scanner;
public class revisonTest {
public static void main(String[] args) // where program exicutes 
{
    final int numOFitems = 50;
    
    String[] item = new String[numOFitems];
    int [] broughtItem = new int[numOFitems];
    int[] costItem =  new int[numOFitems];
    
    int COUNT = getDetail(item,broughtItem,costItem);
    System.out.println(item[0]);

}
    

public static int getDetail(String[] name,int[] quantities,int[]cost)
{
    int count =1;
    int arrayIndex =0;
    String answer = "";
    while(!(answer.equals("Exit")))
    {
        answer =  userInput("Item"+count+": ");
        if(!(answer.equals("Exit")))
        {
            name[arrayIndex] =  answer;
            quantities[arrayIndex] = Integer.parseInt(userInput("How many "+name[arrayIndex]+" have you brought? "));
            cost[arrayIndex] = Integer.parseInt(userInput("How much does a "+name[arrayIndex]+" cost? "));
            count++;
            arrayIndex++;
            
        }
    }
    return count;
    
}
public static String userInput(String question)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(question);
    return sc.nextLine();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `String[] item = new String[numOFitems];`

1. This first makes a new treasure map named 'item'.
2. This makes a new treasurechest capable of containing `numOFitems` treasuremaps, and buries it in the sand. It is then filled with that many blank maps that lead to no treasure.
3. This updates your `item` treasuremap to point at this treasurechest-containing-maps.

> `getDetail(item,broughtItem,costItem);`

This takes your treasuremap to the treasure-of-maps and makes a copy of it, and then hands the copy to the `getDetail` method. Your copy is unmodified and cannot be modified by `getDetail`... but that's just your copy of the treasure **MAP**, not the treasure. Note that `getDetail` calls this copy `name` and not `item` - which it is free to do.

> (in getDetail) `name[arrayIndex] =  answer;`

This is getDetail taking its `name` treasuremap (which is a copy of main's item map), follows the map, gets a shovel out, digs down, finds the treasure, opens it, finds the `arrayIndex`th map in it, pulls it up, and copies its `answer` map onto it.

Thus.. when main follows its copy of its map to the same treasure, same thing happens.

Of course, in java we use different jargon.

- 'treasure' -> 'object'
- 'treasuremap' -> 'reference'
- 'follow the map, dig down, open treasure' -> 'dereference'.
- 'create treasure' -> 'instantiate an object'

Answer (score 0):

There are two different concepts here:

1. Allocating an array and assigning an array reference to a variable, and
2. Assigning values to elements in the array

In `main`, the `new` operation creates an array of a certain size, and assigns  a reference to that array to the variable named `item`.

The call of `getDetail(item,...)` makes a copy of that reference (not the array itself) available to the method.  Inside `getDetail`, this reference is stored in what is effectively a local variable, named `name`.

The loop inside `getDetail` is collecting answers (which are actually String references) and storing them in successive elements of the array that it knows as `name` and which the caller knows as `item`.

```
    name[arrayIndex] =  answer;
```

(Similarly for the other two arrays, of course)

In summary, `getDetail` is provided with an existing array, into which it writes values.

Incidentally, if the user types too many answers (more than `name.length`) you'll run off the end of the array, and get an 'index out of bounds' exception.

Comment: I get how it just copy, but then how do arrays in the main method gets assigned

Comment: The array itself is assigned here: `String[] item = new String[numOFitems];` and the array elements are assigned here: `name[arrayIndex] =  answer;`  The **array** is not copied; a **reference to the array** is copied.

Answer (score 0):

A `String` in java is considered a non-primitive data type. So when you created your item array using:

```
String[] item = new String[numOFitems];
```

You actually created an empty array of `String` objects. Based on your code the array has `50` empty spaces where you can store data.

The next part of your code is designed to get input from the user and fill those arrays:

```
int COUNT = getDetail(item,broughtItem,costItem);
```

> Note: `getDetail()` never returns the `item[]` array, so how do you access the data?

When you pass your `item` array as an argument to the `getDetail()` method, you are actually passing that array as a reference.

In Java, non-primitive data types are passed as reference. This means that instead of sending the data to the `getDetail()` method, your actually sending information about where the data is located in memory.

Within your `getDetail()` method you can manipulate the data and the changes will be reflected on the original array without having to return it.

That is the reason why your print statement shows data in the array:

```
System.out.println(item[0]);
```

Any changes made within the `getDetail()` method, to the array, automatically appear on the original data source.